# Why has my interface been Squashed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, storyboard

I recently converted my project from ios4 using xib files to ios6 using a storyboard. After converting the central buttons within my interface have become squashed together. I am using autolayout with my storyboard.

*StoryBoardView:*
[image]

IPhone 6.0 Emulator view
[image]

*AppDelegate code used to swap xib and StoryBoard*

```
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                              bundle:nil];
self.viewController = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
//self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];//Change this back if all doesnt not go well
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of the autolayout. You have constraints that are adjusting your objects. If you want to use autoLayout I suggest you watch the WWDC video "Session 202 - Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X" and/or read [Understanding Autolayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/UnderstandingAutolayout.html)

Comment: I've turned off auto-layout and all is not well.
http://gyazo.com/482106f1d5ac70f5d7df00d76ea62da1.png?1360710596

Comment: With the screen shot you posted. You can see that autolayout is no longer squeezing your objects together. How large is the storyboard view you are working on in IB? it looks like it is larger then the view you are displaying. You need to look into how to properly use autolayout or autoresizing masks.